# Move a picture from my app storage to DCIM or Pictures directory on android 10+

Tags: java, android, image, storage, mediastore

I want to move a file say randompic.png to `DCIM` or `Pictures` directory so that user does not loose the file after uninstalling the app. *I don't want to use LegacyStorage.* I've search many times and tried many fix but I wasn't able to move the files. How to do this with ConentResolver and MediaStore api?

Comment: `a file say randompic.png` Please start with telling full path of file.

Comment: Further you can copy the file to the MediaStore and delete the original. Use the .insert() member function. You will get an uri for which you can open an outputstream to wich you can write the bytes of the file.

Comment: [This project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos) demonstrates downloading a video into `Movies/` using `MediaStore`. You would take a similar approach, swapping in your local file as the data source and the different `MediaStore` collection as the destination.